# Spring's "<form:select.." doesn't work, HTTP Status 400

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

"Project"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project extends NamedEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "start_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date startDate;

@Column(name = "end_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date endDate;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "notes")
private String notes;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "project_status_id")
private ProjectStatus projectStatus;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "project_objective_id")
private ProjectObjective projectObjective;

// Getters & Setters...
}
```

"ProjectStatus"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project_statuses")
public class ProjectStatus {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

// Getters & Setters...
}
```

"ProjectObjective"

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project_objectives")
public class ProjectObjective {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

// Getters & Setters...
}
```

"Controller"

```
@Controller
public class ProjectController {

@Autowired
private FirmManagerService firmManagerService;

@ModelAttribute("statuses")
public Collection<ProjectStatus> populateProjectStatuses() {
    return this.firmManagerService.findProjectStatuses();
}

@ModelAttribute("objectives")
public Collection<ProjectObjective> populateProjectObjectives() {
    return this.firmManagerService.findProjectObjectives();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/projects/{projectId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initUpdateProjectForm(@PathVariable("projectId") long projectId, Model model) {
    Project project = this.firmManagerService.findProjectById(projectId);
    model.addAttribute("project", project);
    return "projects/createOrUpdateProject";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/projects/{projectId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processUpdateProjectForm(@ModelAttribute("project") Project project, ModelMap model) {
    model.put("project", project);
        return "projects/testEditProjectPage";
}
//...
}
```

JSP "createOrUpdateProject"

```
 <form:form modelAttribute="project" method="post" action="/projects/${project.id}/edit"
               class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${project.id}"/>
           <label>Name</label>
              <form:input class="form-control" path="name"/>
           <label>Start Date</label>
              <form:input class="form-control" path="startDate"/>
           <label>End Date</label>
              <form:input class="form-control" path="endDate"/>
           <label>Description</label>
              <form:input class="form-control" path="description"/>
           <label>Notes</label>
              <form:input class="form-control" path="notes"/>


            <label>Project's Status</label>
            <form:select class="form-control" path="projectStatus" items="${statuses}" size="4"/>
           <label>Project's Objective</label>
            <form:select class="form-control" path="projectObjective" items="${objectives}" size="7"/>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Update Project</button>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

JSP "testEditProjectPage"

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <td><b><c:out value="${project.id}"/></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td><b><c:out value="${project.name}"/></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Status ID</th>
    <td><c:out value="${project.projectStatus.id}"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Status</th>
    <td><c:out value="${project.projectStatus.name}"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Objective ID</th>
    <td><c:out value="${project.projectObjective.id}"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Objective</th>
    <td><c:out value="${project.projectObjective.name}"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Description</th>
    <td><c:out value="${project.description}"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Notes</th>
    <td><c:out value="${project.notes}"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Start date</th>
    <td><fmt:formatDate value="${project.startDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>End date</th>
    <td><fmt:formatDate value="${project.endDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/></td>
</tr>
```

Project has projectStatus and projectObjective. The problem is that if i'm POSTing "project" with fields "projectStatus" and "projectObjective" by using spring's "form: select", i have got an HTTP 400 error (The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.).

[SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaprO.jpg)

If i'm excluding these two selects from JSP form, it properly shows recently POSTed project, but of course with NULL status and objective fields.

[SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcSVy.jpg)

Please!! Clarify me, how to properly use this "form:select" for POSTing data. Because of this problem i can't "EDIT" project (by using entityManager.merge(project)) since "id" and "name" fields of projectStatus and projectObjective are NULL:(

I wrote this project by using Spring's PetClinic code. In PetClinic it works just fine. I have same fields "projectStatus" and "projectObjective" just like "type" in PetClinic's "Pet" entity
Like that:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="pet"
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${pet.id}"/>
            <form:input class="form-control" path="name"/>
            <form:input class="form-control" path="birthDate"/>
            <form:select class="form-control" path="type" items="${types}" size="5"/>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Update Pet</button>
    </form:form>
```

Comment: Instead of JSTL select use normal HTML select

Answer (score 0):

Use of  form:select tag :

```
 <form:select class="form-control" path=" " id=" ">
    <form:option value ="" selected="Selected"> - Select -</form:option>
        <c:if test="${!empty listname}">
            <c:forEach items=" " var=" ">
                <c:choose>
                ....

                </c:choose>
            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
</form:select>
```